# Creating new branch without repo history to avoid long push time

Tags: git

I have a quite big GIT repository. That is, my `.git` folder is roughly 2Gb. Whenever I create a new branch with `git checkout -b new_branch` and want to push my changes with `git push --set-upstream origin new_branch` it takes quite some time to push new branch. I guess this is because of the huge `.git` folder. Is there any way to create a new branch without the complete history to speed up the workflow?

Comment: A push of a new branch based on history that already exists on the remote should not take significantly more time if the history is long, because your local git and the remote already share most of the information (and git is quite efficient at avoiding unnecessary transfers). Does the new branch itself contain a lots of big files that need to be transferred (i.e. that are different from any previous files in the repo)? Which parts of the git push takes a long time (what's the last line printed while you're waiting)?

Comment: no the new branch actually only changes some code fragments, no new data or other big files are created actually. Its the upload step that takes quite a while and prints that 2gb needs to be pushed

Comment: "some code fragments": how many files are touched and how big are those files? Is it possible that the code is not stored in individual/small files but in some big archive? Some tools tend to store stuff like that and that would be bad for git. For now everything you describe suggests strongly that there *are* big changes in the new branch.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to create completely new branch without parent, then do the following [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---orphanltnew-branchgt)

```
git checkout --orphan branchname

git rm -rf .
```